# SVM on 1 dimensional data

Tags: svm

I have a data vector which I have annotated. But it only includes one feature, and data is generally on dimensional.

Is there any way to apply SVM on 1-dimensional data?

Comment: How many data points are there?

Comment: thank you for your comment. at least 400 are in my vector

Comment: I'm going to test decision tree, but I'm seeking for a way of using SVM either.

Comment: Its not really necessary to use SVM here. You can search for the best threshold.